# Uncertainty due to assuming a variable is constant - Adiabatic Invariance

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, error-analysis

I am studying classical mechanics from Goldstein and I ran into a confusing equation in the textbook. In the third edition of the book, equation (12.92) calcucates the average change of the action variable $J$ over some period of time $\tau$ given that the Hamiltonian depends on some slowly changing variable $a$.

In this equation, Goldstein states "since $a$ varies slowly, $a$ can be taken as a constant during this interval...". Which then follows the steps (simplified here):

$$\int_{\tau} dt  \dot{a} = \dot{a} \int_{\tau}dt + O(\dot{a}^2, \ddot{a})$$

From what I understand here, by assuming $\dot{a}$ is constant in this integral, we have introduced errors proportional to the: quadratic of $\dot{a}$, and $\ddot{a}$.

I don't understand why this is the case? I can see how errors proportional to $\ddot{a}$ arise by expanding in time, but I don't understand how we have introduced errors proportional to $\dot{a}^2$.

Comment: Because in the formula $\int_{\tau} dt  \dot{a} = \dot{a} \int_{\tau}dt + O(\dot{a}^2, \ddot{a})$ you took the integral to be approximately proportional to $\dot a$ by assuming that $\dot a$ is a constant over the time interval $\tau$ you are integrating over, therefore the error must be higher than 1st order in the same term.

Comment: Hi, I see what your getting at but I don't really fully understand it. Is there a more rigorous (not like a full mathmatical proof or anything) way to show such deduction?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov%E2%80%93Bogoliubov_averaging_method and their book N. M. Krylov; N. N. Bogolyubov (1947). Introduction to non-linear mechanics. Princeton: Princeton Univ. Press. ISBN 9780691079851.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few days, I finally got my answer. The answer is: we expand the integral in terms of $\dot{a}$

Goldstein states that "$a$ varies slowly..." so, therefore $\dot{a}$ is NOT constant, but rather small! So if we let the integral be

$$f(\dot{a}) = \int \dot{a} dt$$

then expanding would be:

$$f(\dot{a}) \approx f(0) +f'(0)\dot{a} +f''(0) \dot{a}^2/2 +...$$

with
$$f'(0) = \int dt$$

so thus

$$\int \dot{a} dt \approx \dot{a}\int dt + O(\dot{a}^2)$$

In summary, NO Goldstein did not simply pull the $\dot{a}$ out of the integral because its approximately constant, but rather, expanded the integral in series because $\dot{a}$ is small. Thanks for reading.

Edit: I know this result is not rigor (nor exactly correct... since $\dot{a}$ here changes in time, and therefore the expansion shown above is not exactly correct. I am ok with this answer but if you have a bette answer, please post them below)